# Php helper function parameter undefined

Tags: php, laravel, helper

In my Laravel 5.4 project I've got a `Helpers.php` file. That's working great.

Now I've made a helper that looks like this:

```
if (! function_exists('issetWithReturn')) {
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    function issetWithReturn($values)
    {
        return isset($collection) ? $collection : '';
    }
}
```

In my `OrganisationController.php` I use it like this:

```
/**
 * Show all organisations.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function index()
{
    if (Gate::allows('edit-organisations')) {
        $products = $this->productRepo->getAll();
    }

    return view('organisation.index')->with([
        'products'   => issetWithReturn($products),
    ]);
}
```

But my editor already gives a sign that `$products` within `issetWithReturn` is undefined? Why is that?

When I try this it's all working:

```
'products'   => isset($products) ? $products : '',
```

Comment: did you include helper file?

Comment: Yes I use more helper functions and they are working correctly. It's in my ```composer.json```. I ran ```composer dumpautoload -o```. But that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are passing a parameter called `$values` but inside the function using a varible called `$collection`

So basically its a typo

```
if (! function_exists('issetWithReturn')) {
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    function issetWithReturn($values)
    {
        return isset($value) ? $value : '';
    }
}
```